# How to get the keystrokes from the android soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to authenticate users in my app by their keystrokes on the soft keyboard, I want to get:

- The key release and press.
- the pressure on the key.
- the finger area on the key.

I used the `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` but It doesn"t work.
So how can I get these events from the soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `onKeyDown` from the view, override `dispatchKeyEvent` at the activity level. This will handle your key event before it gets to the window manager, so make sure to call super on any key events you do not explicitly handle. Example using the `ACTION_DOWN` (as every event has both `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN`)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for our answer ! actually, i'm looking to get the hold time of whatever key the user press, so I did this :